# Trouble with datetime

Tags: python, join, datetime-format, strptime

Yet another silly programming attempt on my part. This beauty searches through a file (that part was simplified in the example, no issues with that) for a start date and end date of something and tries to convert it to local time for nefarious purposes. 
Here's what I managed to put together ( remember, newbie coder here):

```
#will need it later#
import datetime
#this part simulates other code that opens a 
#file for me. The format of date and time
#is preserved
mail_body = """
Maintenance Date/Time (Local): 
Nov 17 2017 00:01 CET - Nov 17 2017 06:00 CET
Maintenance Date/Time (GMT):
Nov 16 2017 23:30 GMT - Nov 17 2017 05:00 GMT"""

#Turning it all into list to be able to get important
# bits of text by using index later
word_list = mail_body.split()

# A dictionary to transform months into numbers
months = {
    "Jan":1,"Feb":2,"Mar":3,"Apr":4,
    "May":5,"Jun":6,"Jul":7,"Aug":8,
    "Sep":9,"Oct":10,"Nov":11,"Dec":12
    }

#Various lists    
start_date = []
start_date_local = []


# Will need that to convert GMT to my local GMT + 1
add_hour = datetime.timedelta(hours = 1)
gmt = word_list.index("(GMT):")

#Grabbing parts of the text I need by selecting
#index numbers
def get_gmt(x):
    start_date.extend(word_list[gmt + 1:gmt + 5])
    end_date.extend(word_list[gmt + 7:gmt + 11])
    #print (",".join(start_date))
    return (",".join(start_date))


#Attempting to add +1 hour in a safe way, program
#needs to know it's working with dates
def start_local(x):

#Where the pain starts.....must be string, not list
#Not really sure how to get around that
    start_date_local = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M")
    start_date_local = start_date_local + add_hour
    return start_date_local


#Calling functions
get_gmt(word_list)
start_date
start_local(start_date)
```

The issue starts with the .strptime(). I am unable to convert start_date into format that strptime will accept. Yes, I have read many answers on those boards, also read the documentation  for strptime (not that I understand it). .join() didn't seem to help, maybe I am using it the wrong way. If anyone decides to help me then please, keep it simple. I don't really mind if the code will be inelegant, my only requirement is that it works and I know why it works.

Comment: Don't be so self-deprecating, it's not good for you and it doesn't help make the question objective. What would the ideal output of your code look like from `mail_body`?

Comment: Year, month, day, hour, minute will do. I will probably have to split it again afterwards. Just "," between them if that's possible. If not then any separator is fine as long as it's used consistently.

Comment: Yeah, but a nested list? `[[entry_1_start_dt, entry_1_end_dt], [entry_2_start_dt, entry_2_end_dt], ...]`?

Comment: Also, the two entries you show do not have similar durations between GMT and local time.The first one has a duration of 5:59, the other 5:30.

Comment: Not sure what a nested list is, but I think I recognise that pattern. Had some trouble with it previously so if it's possible to avoid that solution........Ideally the simplier it will be the less hassle I will have with it in the future.

Comment: Yes, as you noticed I had to experiment a lot.

Comment: At some point you're going to have to get to grips with this kind of thing. It's fine to be a beginner at programming, but that doesn't give you a get-out to have an easy ride. It's important that you specify the required output format and ensure the input is consistent. How am I to rectify the mismatch in durations?

Comment: Please, just ignore the CET time. I put it there to make sure my code knows to disregard it. Only GMT is significant. As for output separating everything by "," is fine with me. I probably wouldn't know what to do with nested list.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best ways to figure out what is wrong is walking through the code. To begin with, let's make note of a few points:

1. When a function is using a variable, the variable should either
   be passed in as a parameter or be declared inside the function. (Note: This does gloss over certain types of variables but for beginner coders it is something I highly recommend sticking by).
2. Make sure the parameter is being used inside the function. You don't
   want any variables such as `x` that aren't being used.

Looking at this rules, let's edit `get_gmt`. To follow the rules, `get_gmt` should now contain the declarations for `gmt`, `start_date`, and `end_date`. And the parameter should be `word_list`.

```
def get_gmt(word_list):
   gmt = word_list.index("(GMT):")
   start_date = []
   end_date = []
   start_date.extend(word_list[gmt + 1:gmt + 5])
   end_date.extend(word_list[gmt + 7:gmt + 11])
   print(start_date)
   print(end_date)
   return (",".join(start_date))
```

Now that the code is together, it becomes visible that you are initializing the variables `start_date` and `end_date` first and then calling the function `extend` for both lists exactly once. We can condense this into one line declaration and initialization for each variable. This results in the following function:

```
def get_gmt(word_list):
   gmt = word_list.index("(GMT):")
   start_date = word_list[gmt + 1:gmt + 5]
   end_date = word_list[gmt + 7:gmt + 11]
   return (",".join(start_date))
```

Now that the code is much simpler, let's print out what the return value of this function is by changing the call `get_gmt` to `print(get_gmt(word_list))`. This prints out the value `Nov,16,2017,23:30` which is the string returned by `get_gmt`. The format is required by `strptime` is `"%m-%d-%Y %H:%M"`.

Next let's look at the TutorialsPoint example available at this link: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_strptime.htm. If we have the format listed above `Nov,16,2017,23:30` then let's work through each part step by step.

- `Nov` is represented by `%b`
- `16` is represented by `%d` or `%e` (depending on how 1-9 are represented)
- `2017` is represented by `%Y`
- `23:30` is represented by `%H:%M`

Putting that together, since your example a string separated by commas, you have the pattern `%b,%d,%Y,%H:%M` (or `%b,%e,%Y,%H:%M`).

Keep working through your code the same way - walking through each line of code. Two more points to keep in mind:

1. Any time you declare a variable (ex. `end_date`) you should be using it somewhere. If you aren't using it anywhere, that means you don't need it or maybe you need it somewhere else.
2. When you have a return value for a function (ex. `get_gmt`) you should be using it somewhere. You want to store the return value in a variable and (as the previous point states) use the variable somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and good advice. I cleaned up a little as you told me and it looks better. Still, it won't work. I have run it through pythontutor.com. It seems that get_gmt(word_list) is returning a value of  "Nov,16,2017,23:30", but for some reason start_local(start_date) is not being processed despite being called. As if it won't see or receive start_date. It's probably some small mistake in my part but I'm not really sure where to look for it. Let me know if you would like to see the entire code.

Answer (score 0):

As a persistent person I couldn't let the problem be. Being unable to solve the issue with passing arguments from one function to another I got rid of the functions altogether. Sure, they look pretty, sure you can do a lot of things with them (probably), other people can understand the code better. Still, it's all for naught if it won't work. On the plus side I have managed to wrap my head around datetime.strptime, thanks to Nupur Garg. Here's what I came up with:

```
import datetime

mail_body = """
Maintenance Date/Time (Local): 
Nov 17 2017 00:01 CET - Nov 17 2017 06:00 CET
Maintenance Date/Time (GMT):
Nov 16 2017 23:30 GMT - Nov 17 2017 05:00 GMT"""


word_list = mail_body.split()

gmt = word_list.index("(GMT):")
start_date = word_list[gmt + 1:gmt + 5]
start_date = ",".join(start_date)
end_date = word_list[gmt + 7:gmt + 11]
end_date = ",".join(end_date)

add_hour = datetime.timedelta(hours = 1)
start_date_local = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, "%b,%d,%Y,%H:%M")
start_date_local = start_date_local + add_hour
print start_date_local
end_date_local = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_date, "%b,%d,%Y,%H:%M")
end_date_local = end_date_local + add_hour
print end_date_local
```